# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException using Phonegap 3 contacts plugin

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, android-contacts

I have the next problem. I tried to find the solution but I haven't found anything to solve my problem.

I'm new in phonegap development and I'm doing some "tests".
Now, I want to show all contacts in the smartphone.

Following this [enter link description here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_contacts_contacts.md.html#Contacts) , first I add the plugin with:
 cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-contacts.git

but I used phonegap instead of cordova.

Next I add:
(in app/res/xml/config.xml)

```
<feature name="Contacts">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.ContactManager" />
</feature>
```

(in app/AndroidManifest.xml)

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
```

Finally, I used the full example.

But, when I launch the App occurs the next error in Eclipse:
[image]
I don't know how to solve the problem :S

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using the CLI (command line tools) (which you are), you shouldn't need to edit any of the files in `platforms/android/res/config.xml` or `/platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml` because the tools will do that for you.

Anyway, the problem seems to be that `<param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.ContactManager" />` should in fact be     `<param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.contacts.ContactManager" />`.  This is what I get on a fresh install of the CLI.

Can you try to do `npm update -g cordova` (or phonegap) and then run the commands again and see if it works? I'm not sure why the namespace was wrong for you; the change for this was [8 days ago](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-contacts/commit/e646df35e1f710197c63edb81813cfae80d2589f), maybe you are just using an old cordova/phonegap version?

Comment: Yes, indeed. I come to write the solution but I see that you have just written. The solution was very very simple, yes, I know, I'm stupid. I wrote in the config.xml <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.contacts.ContactManager" /> as you say and it works perfect. The problem was only that. Yes, I was using the latest version, everything was right except that line. Thank you very very much!!I hope this problem and solution could be useful to other people.

Answer (score 4):

I had the exact same problem before with inappBrowser the docs are wrong for v 3.3 and up instead of

```
<feature name="InAppBrowser"> 
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.InAppBrowser"/>
</feature>
```

it needs to be

```
<feature name="InAppBrowser"> 
   <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser.InAppBrowser"/>
</feature>
```

you can actually check what't the correct mapping info if you look under

plugins/your-plugin/config.xml

```
 <!-- android -->
    <platform name="android">
        <config-file target="res/xml/config.xml" parent="/*">
            <feature name="InAppBrowser"> 
<param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser.InAppBrowser"/>
</feature>
```

cheers